# Bootstrap class="active" will not work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a issue with getting my bootstrap to work with a site I am designing for a friend.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="brand" href="/" style="width: 240px;">
                West Coast Refuse Trucks
            </a>
            <div class="nav-collapse">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.html" class="active">
                            Home
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="about.html">
                            About
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="firstgear.html">
                            First Gear
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/play">
                            Uploads
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/forums">
                            Refuse Community
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I am not sure what is preventing it from highlighting in my page on my site.  Home shows up as usual. Any help?

Comment: Your HTML code is invalid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Bootstrap 2.3.2, you suppose to add `active` class to `<li>`, not to `<a>`.

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/97634